# Object detection in an image using haar cascade(opencv)

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier

I have around 2000 images and I have to find the images which are having the given "L" shaped object in it as shown below.
[image]

i have used the below images as positive images
[image]
ans the below ones as negatives which is not having the L shaped object.
[image]
and created the xml file(classifier) using using opencv_traincascade method of opencv.
But it is giving some false detection as well along with correct detection any way to increase accuracy

edit: some of the false cases
[image][image]

Comment: Can you attach some false positive cases?

Comment: attached some cases. Also it is not detecting the positive ones in some cases

Comment: Oh I see, since the shape for which you are trying to train model is kind of generic, so it can be easily distracted, (However I can visualize the 'L' in those false positives). I think you need to filter your results, instead of feeding more cases to for training, You can filter the output on area, color, max number of expected objects in a given scene, etc. Get this logic more robust instead of making haar cascade to predict with 100% accuracy, because even the frontal face detector also returns false positive cases in some situations, so do not rely completely on Haar cascades.